# Select class inside another class

Tags: javascript

I want to surround text in class "Inside" (which is inside class "Iztocnica") with symbol "#". If there are no classes "Inside" in class "Iztocnica", I want to add "##".

For example:

**Original:**

Hello Hello

Ola

Hi Hi

**Text I want:**

Hello #Hello#

Ola ##

Hi #Hi#

**Html**

```
<p class=Iztocnica>
    <span class=SomeClass>Hello</span>
    <span class=Inside>Hello</span>
</p>
<p class=Iztocnica>
    <span class=SomeClass>Ola</span>
</p>
<p class=Iztocnica>
    <span class=SomeClass>Hi</span>
    <span class=Inside>Hi</span>
</p>
```

So is there any way to do that with Javascript? I know how to surround text that are in class "Inside", but i don't know how to add "##" if there is no class "Inside"

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("Inside"); // vsi <p>

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
    x[i].innerHTML="#"+x[i].innerHTML+"#";
}
```

Comment: I know how to surround text inside class "Inside", but I have no idea how to add "##" if there is no class "Inside" in class "Iztocnica".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start at Iztocnica class and add an Inside if it doesn't exist in each instance

```js
var izt = document.querySelectorAll('.Iztocnica');

izt.forEach(function(el){
  var inside = el.querySelector('.Inside');
  if(!inside){
      inside = document.createElement('span');
      inside.classList.add('Inside')
      el.appendChild(inside)
  }
  inside.innerHTML="#"+inside.innerHTML+"#";
});
```

```html
<p class=Iztocnica>
    <span class=SomeClass>Hello</span>
    <span class=Inside>Hello</span>
</p>
<p class=Iztocnica>
    <span class=SomeClass>Ola</span>
</p>
<p class=Iztocnica>
    <span class=SomeClass>Hi</span>
    <span class=Inside>Hi</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

It can also be done with [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) :

```css
.Inside:before, .Inside:after { content: "#" }
.Iztocnica :only-child:after { content: " ##" }
```

```html
<p class=Iztocnica>
    <span class=SomeClass>Hello</span>
    <span class=Inside>Hello</span>
</p>
<p class=Iztocnica>
    <span class=SomeClass>Ola</span>
</p>
<p class=Iztocnica>
    <span class=SomeClass>Hi</span>
    <span class=Inside>Hi</span>
</p>
```

---

Or in JavaScript, you can check if `x[i].getElementsByClassName("Inside")` returns any elements.

Answer (score 0):

For **Non** `Inside` span class e.g (`<span class=SomeClass>Ola</span>`), add an extra class `noInside` to those `span` and then append existing `innerHTML` with string `##`.

For `Inside` span class e.g (`<span class=Inside>Hello</span>`), just prepend and append `#` before the actual `innerHTML`.

```js
var inside = document.querySelectorAll("span.Inside"); 
Array.prototype.forEach.call(inside, function (item) {
  item.innerHTML = "#" + item.innerHTML + "#";
});

var noInside = document.querySelectorAll(".noInside"); 
Array.prototype.forEach.call(noInside, function (item2) {
  item2.innerHTML+= " ##";
});
```

```html
<p class=Iztocnica>
    <span class=SomeClass>Hello</span>
    <span class=Inside>Hello</span>
</p>
<p class=Iztocnica>
    <span class="SomeClass noInside">Ola</span>
</p>
<p class=Iztocnica>
    <span class=SomeClass>Hi</span>
    <span class=Inside>Hi</span>
</p>
```

Comment: FYI `querySelectorAll()` does have it's own `forEach()`

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for the info, I don't know it. :) could you please give me a reference ?

Comment: Well I cant add extra class "noInside" to span because I have over 500 "SomeClass-es" in my code and I dont know which "Iztocnica" classes have "Inside" class inside and which dont.

Comment: returns a Nodelist and is method of NodeList https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Comment: @Joe in that case you can follow the other solution. I just thought it'll be a easy solution for you to add an extra class.